# Signal post_save in Django and models

Tags: django, signals, models

I have function with signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Task)
def my_handler():
    executor = User.objects.filter(user_type='Executer')
    executor.balance += Task.money
    executor.save()
```

My function should add money to executor after task added. But it gives mistake like:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/tasks/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/home/k/pro/freelance-django/free/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1853, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Executer'
[20/Sep/2017 14:00:30] "POST /api/v1/tasks/ HTTP/1.1" 500 188088
```

**User class** looks like:

```
   from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    CUSTOMER = 1
    EXECUTER = 2

    USER_TYPES = (
        (CUSTOMER, 'Customer'),
        (EXECUTER, 'Executer'),
    )

    user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPES, default=EXECUTER, verbose_name='Тип пользователя')
    balance = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7, default=0, verbose_name='Баланс')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**Task class** from task.models is:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Описание')
    money = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0, verbose_name='Цена')
    assignee = models.ForeignKey('users.User', related_name='assignee', null=True, verbose_name='Исполнитель')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('users.User', related_name='created_by', verbose_name='Кем был создан')
```

How should I make it work?

Comment: show the task model

Comment: Can you add complete your User model class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**U don't have one *object* but *objects* so you need literal on them or do `update()`. The best option is use F expression which has a good performance because its executed on DB:**

```
from django.db.models import F    

@receiver(post_save, sender=Task)
def my_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    User.objects.filter(user_type=User.EXECUTER).update(balance=F('balance') + instance.money)
```

This update all records where user_type is Executer and update them balance in one query.

[Django docs update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)

[F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model)

**Your `user_type` field is IntegerField and in your choices you have string value so u need change it to something like this:**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    CUSTOMER = 1
    EXECUTER = 2

    USER_TYPES = (
        (CUSTOMER, 'Customer'),
        (EXECUTER, 'Executer'),
    )

    user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPES, default=EXECUTER, verbose_name='Тип пользователя')
    balance = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7, default=0, verbose_name='Баланс')
```

Comment: Thank you, but this solution gives "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Executer'" mistake

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately it still gives mistake, thats why I try all solutions. "    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Executer'
[20/Sep/2017 14:56:29] "POST /api/v1/tasks/ HTTP/1.1" 500 188228"

Comment: I added your code, but same mistake. The only one different is that User inherit from AbstractUser

Comment: Change user_type filter to this: `user_type=User.EXECUTER`

Comment: New mistake))) progress))     (1292, "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7f4366ddada0>'")

Comment: @EkaterinaPremudraya Drop your table and then create again using makemigrations and migrate. This error say that your db store your column as a DOUBLE.

Comment: it goes without broking, but didn't add money to executor

Comment: @EkaterinaPremudraya now I know what is wrong method in signal was without arguments and we dont get value from instance but from class so check my updated signal code and should be fine :D